# Show only last element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my `<li>` I want to show only last element until and unless a button is clicked, then hide the last one  and show the second last one.

I was thinking something like this:

```
var amount = $('#slider > ul li').length);
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#slider').css("opacity", 0);
  $('#slider > ul li').find(amount).css("opacity", 1);
});
```

When I alert `$('#slider > ul li').length)` I get the amount of list items correctly.

It hides all `<li>` correctly with `$('#slider > ul li').length)`.

But when I put the last line in there all li are shown again.

how can I activate only the last one?

Plan is for after this to work to split this up and reduce the counter every time a button is pressed to then again hide all except the second last item (the amount - 1).

Comment: use `last()` and `prev()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set `opacity 0` to the `UL` it will hide all the `li` inside of it. so do like,

CSS:

```
.viewable { opacity : 0; }
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var amount = $('#slider > ul > li');
  amount.not(":last-child").addClass("viewable");
  $("#someBtn").click(function(){
    amount.filter(".viewable").removeClass("viewable").prev().addClass("viewable")
  });
});
```

Also you have to put the element caching code inside of `dom ready` handler. Because it may fail if your js code is in inside of your head.

---

This code will help you better

```
var amount = $('#slider > ul > li');
amount.filter(":last-child").addClass("viewable");
$("#someBtn").click(function () {
    var elem = amount.filter(".viewable").removeClass("viewable").prev();
    elem = elem.length == 0 ? amount.filter(":last-child") : elem;
    elem.addClass("viewable");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4yarxkyg/1/)

Comment: @MartijnKerckhaert The second snippet will work for in a circular manner. Also you could replace the css rule from `opacity 0` to `display none` to hide it and patch the same to your slider.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote two functions, first one to hide all li's except for the last one:

```
function hideListItems(){
    $('#slider ul li').hide(); 
    $('#slider ul li').last().addClass('active').show();
};
```

And another to toggle the previous li:

```
function togglePrevListItem(){
    $('#slider ul li.active').removeClass('active').hide().prev().addClass('active').show();
};
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bab4zr1p/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var lis = $('#slider > ul > li');

  lis.not(lis.filter(':last')).hide();

  function toggleLi() {
    var visible = lis.filter(':visible');

    visible.hide();

    if (visible.prev().length) {
      visible.prev().show();
    }
  }
});
```

call `toggleLi()` whenever you want to unhide the previous list element